# How to modify already added singleton service in .NET host builder?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, ioptionsmonitor

I'm using the new `HostApplicationBuilder` in .NET. I want to use `IOptionsMonitor` to monitor a section of `appsettings.json` for option changes, and apply those changes to Serilog `LoggingLevelSwitch.MinimumLevel` for such an object that's created during host build (using `builder.Services.AddSerilog`).

Something like this:

```csharp
builder.Services.Configure<LoggingOptions>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(key: "Logging"));

LoggingLevelSwitch theSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch(); // Later added to a Serilog sink.

builder.Services.AddSingleton<Something>((serviceProvider) =>
{
    var monitor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<LoggingOptions>>();
    monitor.OnChange((options) => { 
        theSwitch.MinimumLevel = options.MinimumLevel;
    });
}
```

But what do I return from the `AddSingleton` call? I don't really want to add a service, but just add the `OnChange` handler to the singleton for `IOptionsMonitor<LoggingOptions>`.

Without a call such as `builder.Services.AddXXX`, how can I get an `IServiceProvider` instance that I can use to obtain a reference to the `IOptionsMonitor<LoggingOptions>` singleton?

This is supposed to be a helper in a utility package that we can use in multiple different apps to simplify and unify app code and reduce boilerplate code in apps, to allow apps based on .NET hosting to have logging set up and allow the logging level to be modified at runtime.

It would be sufficient to have the `IOptionsMonitor` to be hooked up to the `LoggingLevelSwitch` when the app worker starts and removed when the app worker terminates. But I would like to avoid a requirement on the app author to remember to make extra calls in the worker's start/stop code. So, preferably be able to set this up in the utility package's code that sets up the logging in general.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so the solution was kind-of staring me in the face right from the start.

```csharp
// Apparently this is the new way of binding options, but same semantics as in my question.
builder.Services.AddOptions<LoggingOptions>().BindConfiguration("Logging");

builder.Services.AddSerilog((services, loggerConfiguration) =>
{
    // Create the switch, which will later be applied to a logging sink.
    var levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();

    // Here inside AddSerilog we do have an IServiceProvider,
    // so we can request the IOptionsMonitor<LoggingOptions> singleton.
    // I assume that this is the point where it gets instantiated by the DI container.
    var monitor = services.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<LoggingOptions>>();

    // Here we hook the monitor up to the LoggingLevelSwitch.
    monitor.OnChange(options => levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = options.MinimumLevel);

    // Finally, we can add the sink using the switch,
    // which will be modified by the monitor at runtime.
    loggerConfiguration
        .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
            services.GetRequiredService<TelemetryConfiguration>(),
            TelemetryConverter.Traces,
            levelSwitch: levelSwitch);
});
```

I've tried it in a small console app and it works fine. When I change the logging level in `appsettings.json`, the sink starts receiving log events according to the new setting, without any code within the actual worker service.

Answer (score 0):

I correct myself.
I was wrong, you can achieve this with singleton.

I was able to make it work. I just returned the LoggingLevelSwitch as singleton I was able to se changes in MinimumLevel when appsetting value is changed.

Comment: As far as I understand, singleton will be created either when registered to the container/builder or on the first request for the instance, and on subsequent requests the same instance will be returned, as opposed to creating new instances. This is the exact semantic that I'm after: During build I want the `IOptionsMonitor` to be created and hooked up to the `LoggingLevelSwitch`.

Comment: As far as I understand, the actual registration of the `IOptionsMonitor` singletons (a generic descriptor?) is done by the framework. I just need a way to access it to hook my handler into its `OnChange` event. Doing it in the worker is trivial (just add an `IOptionsMonitor<LoggingOptions>` arg to its constructor), but I want to do it in my util package's code, so it's "automatic" (part of the method that sets up the rest of the logging services).

Comment: I was able to make it work

Comment: OK, that would be possible obviously, but the `LoggingLevelSwitch` isn't actually needed in the DI container so returning it just adds "noise" to the container. Also, if the app were to have a need for a `LoggingLevelSwitch` in the DI container, there could be problems. I found a better solution. Thanks anyway for your efforts!